# Динамическое создание div через JS

Tags: javascript

Постараюсь объяснить что мне надо сделать. У меня есть `json` файл который я получаю с помощью `GET` запроса, после чего я создаю 10 `div` с помощью

```
var count = data.length;
var wrapperEl = document.querySelector('.dots-wrapper');
wrapperEl.innerHTML = Array(count).fill('<div id="img0" class="dot">1</div>').join('');
```

Теперь мне нужно чтобы после каждого созданного блока у него прибавлялся `id`.
Пример:

```
<div id="img0" class="dot">1</div>
<div id="img1" class="dot">1</div>
<div id="img2" class="dot">1</div>
```

и т.д.

Comment: Так используйте просто обычный цикл, в чём проблема?)

Comment: надо изначально создавать нормально, а не пытаться потом исправить. Что вам мешает сделать `while(count--) str += ``<div id="id${count}"></div>``` какой нибудь?